# Запись в массив нужных элементов python

Tags: python

Есть массив

```
arr = ['This next 546468456 fire again go',
      '\n\r\nThis next 281548547 fire again go',
      '\r\nThis next 466865789 fire again go',
      'This next 123456789 fire again go']
```

Нужно переписать данные в таком виде

```
arr = ['This 546468456 fire go',
      'This 281548547 fire go',
      'This 466865789 fire go',
      'This 123456789 fire go']
```

Незнаю как сделать. Если у вас пример

Comment: и что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень красиво но наглядно как это можно сделать.

```
arr = ['This next 546468456 fire again go',
      '\n\r\nThis next 281548547 fire again go',
      '\r\nThis next 466865789 fire again go',
      'This next 123456789 fire again go']
arr_new = []
for i in arr:
    text = i.replace('\n','').replace('\r','').split(' ')
    data = []
    for j in text:
        if 'This' or 'fire' or 'go' in j:
            data.append(j)
        elif j.isdigit() is True:
            data.append(j)
    arr_new.append(' '.join(data))
print(arr_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

вы бы задачу ставили чётко, может после этого у вас бы не было `Незнаю как сделать`

т.е. требуется

1. удалить все `\n\r` с боков (подозреваю, что вообще удалить с боков пробельные и т.п. символы)
2. удалить слово `again`

Т.е.

1. для удаления слова `again` лучше воспользоваться методом `.replace()`
2. для удаления пробельных символов по бокам лучше воспользоваться методом `.strip()`
3. надо пройти по всем элементам массива используя 1) и 2) и собрать новый массив